# Column from multiple CONTAINSSTRING()

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am newbie with powerbi.
I need to filter a column by multiple string and multiple value.
I tried this DAX:

```
New Column = 
CONTAINSSTRING('Creator'[Name], "Que" ), "Need to report" 
|| CONTAINSSTRING('Name'[Creator], "In/Waiting" ), "Need to wait" 
|| CONTAINSSTRING('Creator'[Name], "In/Landing"), "Need to release"
```

My expectation, when the column `Name` is `Que` then the value in the `New Column` become "Need to report`, if` In/Waiting`then`Need to wait` and so on.

Anyone can help me some idea about it?
I really appreciated. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
New Column = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    CONTAINSSTRING('Creator'[Name], "Que" ), "Need to report",
    CONTAINSSTRING('Creator'[Name], "In/Waiting" ), "Need to wait", 
    CONTAINSSTRING('Creator'[Name], "In/Landing"), "Need to release"
)
```

[image]